# How to get rows under a specific string value with SQL

Tags: sql

I want to create a query to fetch all the data under a specific value that is a string.

Let me use this table to make myself clear and let's call it staff.

```
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| jobs    | person      | age  | Gender|
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| teacher | marcus      |  32  |   M   |
| nurse   | alice       |  27  |   F   | 
| gardener| leonard     |  26  |   M   | 
| doctor  | greg        |  45  |   M   |
| pilot   | rachel      |  22  |   F   | 
| driver  | jean        |  24  |   M   | 
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
```

How can I create a query that me returns all the values **below** 'doctor'?

Desired Result below

```
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| jobs    | person      | age  | Gender|
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| pilot   | rachel      |  22  |   F   | 
| driver  | jean        |  24  |   M   | 
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: You did not name the table. You need to add the database version and name. assuming table name 'thetable', just use `select distinct species from thetable` or `select species from thetable group by species`

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Sorry, I just saw I didn't explain my problem correctly. I've made the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make it clear what "below" is supposed to mean.

A table, by itself, **has no inherent ordering** according to the definition of SQL. If you just ask the database "Give me all the rows in the table" it is allowed to return them in any order it feels like. Both of these are permissible responses to the simple query `SELECT * FROM staff`:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| jobs    | person      | age  | Gender|
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| teacher | marcus      |  32  |   M   |
| nurse   | alice       |  27  |   F   | 
| gardener| leonard     |  26  |   M   | 
| doctor  | greg        |  45  |   M   |
| pilot   | rachel      |  22  |   F   | 
| driver  | jean        |  24  |   M   | 
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| jobs    | person      | age  | Gender|
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| pilot   | rachel      |  22  |   F   | 
| driver  | jean        |  24  |   M   | 
| nurse   | alice       |  27  |   F   | 
| teacher | marcus      |  32  |   M   |
| doctor  | greg        |  45  |   M   |
| gardener| leonard     |  26  |   M   | 
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
```

If you add the `ORDER BY` clause, then you can depend on getting them in a known order, and then "below doctor" can mean something:

```
SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY jobs
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| jobs    | person      | age  | Gender|
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| doctor  | greg        |  45  |   M   |
| driver  | jean        |  24  |   M   | 
| gardener| leonard     |  26  |   M   | 
| nurse   | alice       |  27  |   F   | 
| pilot   | rachel      |  22  |   F   | 
| teacher | marcus      |  32  |   M   |
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
```

Now you can ask for all items "below" doctor -- more specifically, all items where the value of jobs is alphabetically after the value "doctor":

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE jobs > 'doctor' ORDER BY jobs
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| jobs    | person      | age  | Gender|
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| driver  | jean        |  24  |   M   | 
| gardener| leonard     |  26  |   M   | 
| nurse   | alice       |  27  |   F   | 
| pilot   | rachel      |  22  |   F   | 
| teacher | marcus      |  32  |   M   |
+---------+-------------+------+-------+
```

But this does not match your request.  Unfortunately, there is **NO** `ORDER BY` clause that works with the data you gave that will put them in the order you gave.

The most common way out of this mess -- i.e., "PLEASE, database, keep the rows in the apparently random order that they were inserted!" -- is to add a `DATE` or `INT` column.

```
+---+---------+-------------+------+-------+
|id | jobs    | person      | age  | Gender|
+---+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| 1 | teacher | marcus      |  32  |   M   |
| 2 | nurse   | alice       |  27  |   F   | 
| 3 | gardener| leonard     |  26  |   M   | 
| 4 | doctor  | greg        |  45  |   M   |
| 5 | pilot   | rachel      |  22  |   F   | 
| 6 | driver  | jean        |  24  |   M   | 
+-------------+-------------+------+-------+
```

Now you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id > 4
+---+---------+-------------+------+-------+
|id | jobs    | person      | age  | Gender|
+---+---------+-------------+------+-------+
| 5 | pilot   | rachel      |  22  |   F   | 
| 6 | driver  | jean        |  24  |   M   | 
+-------------+-------------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the values in the `species` column, you can use:

```
select distinct species
from t;
```

However, when I want this information, the count is usually helpful as well, so I tend to use `group by`:

```
select species, count(*)
from t
group by species;
```

Comment: Sorry, I just saw I didn't explain my problem correctly. I've made the changes